# SDL change rendering size of viewport independent of window

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I want to be able to set it so that say 1 pixel in SDL is 20x20 pixels. If I was using raw OpenGL I would just change the viewport size to a lower resolution with the same aspect ratio of the window. However there don't seem to be a straightforward way to do this with SDL2.

One obvious way would to apply scaling to to all the pixels and textures that are drawn, however the requires a lot of extra work that I believe is not necessary.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize and https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetScale

Comment: @keltar Awesome, exactly what I needed. Not sure how I missed that in the docs! If you make an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize) or [SDL_RenderSetScale](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetScale). This will not affect pointer events (mouse/touch/...), you might need to manually transform them into your virtual resolution.

Comment: Actually in 2.0.8 (don't know if it's the same for previous versions) mouse and touch events are remapped correctly for the logical size of the renderer